# need additional validation

Tags: validation

I am looking for a simple way to perform an input validation or input control in newdocset.aspx. I need to avoid any “.” (dot) in the name to avoid a later performed path generation.  I have tried with JavaScript so far but this seems to be the wrong approach. I am wondering if someone might have this check performed already or have other experiences from similar issues. Cheers.